# Async Await with Task.Run method for DB call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

We have an async/await method `GetLoanDataAsync` which calls a stored procedurre through entity framework which is being called by a sync method `GetData`.

`GetLoanData` takes a good amount of time to execute and probably that was the reason that we wrote as async/await which can be used by multiple places.

I understand that we shouldn't mix async and sync calls but let's say if we have this scenario and we are using `Task.Run()` to call async method `GetLoanDataAsync` from sync method `GetData` which I understand that method - `GetLoanDataAsync` will run on a background thread.

My question is that what if we had a sync version of async method `GetLoanDataAsync` and called using `Task.Run()` from `GetData` than what difference it would make in this case?

Providing more details regarding the issue-

We have ASP.NET REST Web API which return type is not a Task. This is called from angular app. This api has few methods called GetData() and where we wait for the result from `GetLoanDataAsync`. As per my understanding `GetLoanDataAsync` will be called in background thread and will be able to execute `GetUserDetails()`, once this finish it will give back the result from executed `GetLoanDataAsync`.

Code -

```
public List<int> GetData(int id)
{

    // Calls GetLoanDataAsync

    var result = Task.Run(()=> GetLoanDataAsync(id));

    // calls couple other sync methods

    GetUserDetails(); 

    return result.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

}
```

`GetLoanDataAsync().Result` will result in deadlock which was the earlier issue. To fix this we are temporarily trying to use Task.Run till we make overall api as an async.

Comment: What do you do with the result of Task.Run()? Do you wait for the Task to be completed? If yes, then this is not really different from using a sync version in the first place.

Comment: What kind of app is this for? Web? Winforms? Service?

Comment: Remember that asynchronous != parallel. Asynchronous means that the thread is freed while it waits. Parallel means 2 or more things are happening at the same time (on different threads). `Task.Run` will put it on a different thread. Since it's an async method, the [waiting happens nowhere](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: Seeing actual code would help. What does `GetData` look like? How it is called? What kind of application is it (desktop, web, etc.)?

Comment: If this is in a web context, this is a bad idea, because ASP.NET has a limited thread pool and `Task.Run()` will take up one of those precious threads. If the database call is truly async and you are calling it from a synchronous/blocking thread, then your best bet is to say `var result = GetLoanDataAsync().Result`.

Comment: @howcheng GetLoanDataAsync().Result will result in deadlock which was the earlier issue. To fix this we are temporarily trying to use Task.Run till we make overall api as async.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Thank you for the article, will have a look.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you are calling `.Result` in a non-async method in combination with an await somewhere in your call stack, then yes you get a deadlock. But since you didn't specify, I didn't want to assume that.

Comment: So why can't `public List GetData(int id)` be async? Wouldn't that be the simplest solution?

Comment: @howcheng I was calling .Result on non async method but that certainly results in deadlock as we checked. We don't have any await prior to this method call GetData(). We can't do the change as that would require whoever is calling and which we want to avoid as of now.

Comment: Updating every method that calls it feels like a big task, but in my experience, it can be done very quickly. Just change it to `async Task<List<int>>`, compile, and fix everything the compiler complains about, and repeat until it stops complaining. Unless this is a library that you're using in other applications, then that's a different story.

Comment: @GabrielLuci - That code is shared by other projects which can certainly be changed but we are trying to reduce no of changes in files, yeah VS can certainly help if we change the type :) also in of the similar code we have call to PostAsync of HttpClient and use.Result like - httpClient.PostAsync(GetLoanDataURL, loanData, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter()).Result; which doesn't fail. That is called under similar sync method. Not sure why this won't fail or create deadlock....

Answer (score 4):

If you compare a sync vs async version, then the most obvious difference is that the sync version is tying up a thread for the duration of the DB call, which seems unnecessary if all the work is at the database. Whether this is a *problem* depends on your throughput.

By using `Task.Run`, you're allowing that operation to run in *parallel* with other work. This is fine, as long as you don't have any touch-points that impact thread-safety, or which depend on a single logical execution flow.

If you want to use async effectively, it is best to consider it "sticky" - i.e. if X is async, then everything that calls X (directly or indirectly) needs to be async.